# JQuery select function not showing div

Tags: jquery

I have a JQuery function (with the help of another Stackoverflow post) that hides/shows divs depending on what is currently selected on a select/dropdown. This works fine.

When I edit a record the stored value of the select field is displayed in the select/dropdown but the corresponding div remains hidden until a change is made on the select field.

***Code***

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.jshideshow').hide();
        $('#id_selection_basis').change(function () {
            $('.jshideshow').hide();
            $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
        })
    }); 
</script>
```

I have tried various combinations of the above code to show the div straight away on the Update View value but all have so far been unsuccessful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add `relevant` HTML in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a small epiphany I think I have found a solution. Hopefully it might help anyone else with a similar problem.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.jshideshow').hide();
        var failureValue = $( "#id_selection_basis" ).val();
        $('#' + failureValue).show();

        $('#id_selection_basis').change(function () {
            $('.jshideshow').hide();
            $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
        })

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post the corresponding HTML, I'm having trouble understanding your exact issue but I broke down exactly what your code is doing so you might be able to figure it out from there.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.jshideshow').hide(); // 1

        $('#id_selection_basis').change(function () {
            $('.jshideshow').hide(); // 2
            $('#'+$(this).val()).show(); // 3
        })

    }); 
</script>
```

1. Since you're hiding `.jshideshow` by default, set `display: none` either inline on the element in your html or add it to the css class (this isn't causing your issue though)
2. This also hides `.jshideshow` - why do you need to hide something that's already hidden? This makes sense if all divs to show/hide have this class so they're hidden before you call `.show()` on the target element (see #3)
3. This displays whatever element is contained in the value of `#id_selection_basis`

If you're adding elements to `#id_selection_basis` you need to listen for the change event with `$(document).on('change', '#id_selection_basis', function () { ... })`. Event listeners are bound to the DOM on page load so if you add an element to the DOM after page load, you need to listen for it on `$(document)`.

Comment: Hi @Brian, This is demo from which I got the code: http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/wSW7z/ This works fine. However when I open an Update View in Django and the select/dropdown has a value, the corresponding div remains hidden until a 'change' occurs on the select/dropdown. Hope this makes sense and thanks for the help.

Comment: @Karl you're hiding `.jshideshow` on page load and it won't show again until the `change` event is fired. Don't hide the div you want to display on load.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think ive found a solution. Not sure how elegant it is but it seems to do the trick! Thanks again.